# How can i select every 2nd div starting from 3rd?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I am trying to figure out how can I select every 2nd div tag , starting from 3rd div IN CSS .

1. div
2. div
3. div
4. div
5. div
6. div
7. div
8. div
9. div

Any Help will be good

Comment: in what language? html? css?

Comment: thats why i tagged css , html

Comment: a small research and you will get the answer here ... a lot of question related to this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need to do is , `div:nth-child(2n+3)`

Here is a [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Panther_007/r3zkx7my/)